# Rendering HTML for a navigation menu using a class

Tags: php, object-oriented

Below I have implemented a class that will generate HTML to build the structure for a navigation menu.

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/site');

class Navigation
{
    private $doc;
    private $xpath;
    private $rootNode;

    /**
     * Initialize navigation.
     */
    public function __construct($menu)
    {
        $this->doc = new DOMDocument();
        $this->doc->appendChild($this->buildMenu($menu));
        $this->xpath = new DOMXpath($this->doc);
    }

    /**
     * Un-mark selected menu item.
     */
    public function deselect()
    {
        $liNodeList = $this->xpath->query("//li[contains(@class, 'selected')]");
        if ($liNodeList->length) {
            $liNode = $liNodeList->item(0);
            $classAttr = explode(' ', $liNode->getAttribute('class'));
            $key = array_search('selected', $classAttr);
            unset($classAttr[$key]);    
            $liNode->setAttribute('class', implode(' ', $classAttr));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Mark first occurrence of menu item containing link with URI as selected.
     * @param   $uri    string
     */
    public function select($uri)
    {
        $liNodeList = $this->xpath->query("//li[a[contains(@href, '" . $uri . "')]]");
        if ($liNodeList->length) {
            $liNode = $liNodeList->item(0);
            $classAttr = explode(' ', $liNode->getAttribute('class'));
            $classAttr[] = 'selected';
            $liNode->setAttribute('class', trim(implode(' ', $classAttr)));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Build menu.
     * @param   $menu   array
     * @param   $depth  int
     */
    private function buildMenu($menu, $depth = 0) 
    {
        $divNode = $this->createNav();
        $ulNode = $this->doc->createElement('ul');
        // set first nav as root
        if (!$depth) {
            $divNode->setAttribute('id', 'primary-nav');
            $this->rootNode = $divNode;
        }
        // add menu items
        foreach ($menu as $index => $menuItem) {
            $ulNode->appendChild($this->buildMenuItem($menuItem, $depth, $index));
        }
        $divNode->appendChild($ulNode);

        return $divNode;
    }

    /**
     * Build menu.
     * @param   $menu   array
     * @param   $depth  int
     * @param   $index  int
     */
    private function buildMenuItem($menuItem, $depth, $index) 
    {   
        $liNode = $this->doc->createElement('li');
        $aNode = $this->doc->createElement('a');
        // add class attribute
        $classAttr = array();   
        if (isset($menuItem['class'])) {
            $classAttr[] = $menuItem['class'];  
        }
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $menuItem['url']) !== false) {
            $classAttr[] = 'selected';
        }
        if ($classAttr) {
            $liNode->setAttribute('class', implode(' ', $classAttr));
        }
        // add target attribute
        if (isset($menuItem['target'])) {
            $liNode->setAttribute('target', $menuItem['target']);
        }
        // set absolute URL
        if (strpos($menuItem['url'], 'http') === false) {
            $menuItem['url'] = BASE_URL . '/' . $menuItem['url'];
        }
        $aNode->setAttribute('href', $menuItem['url']);
        // add link
        $aNode->nodeValue = $menuItem['text'];
        $liNode->appendChild($aNode);
        // add menu items       
        if (isset($menuItem['menu'])) {
            $liNode->appendChild($this->buildMenu($menuItem['menu'], $depth + 1));
        }

        return $liNode;
    }

    /**
     * Get menu.
     */
    public function getMenu()
    {
        return $this->doc->saveHTML();
    }

    /**
     * Create nav element that will wrap list.
     */
    private function createNav()
    {
        $divNode = $this->doc->createElement('div');
        $divNode->setAttribute('class', 'nav');
        return $divNode;
    }

    /**
     * Check if node element is nav element i.e. has 'nav' class name
     * @param   $node   DOMElement
     */
    private function isNav(DOMElement $node)
    {
        return array_search('nav', explode(' ', $node->getAttribute('class'))) !== false;
    }
}
```

This is how it would be used:

```
$menu = array(
    array(
        "text" => "Nav Item 1", 
        "url" => "page1.php"
    ),
    array(
        "text"  => "Nav Item 2", 
        "url"   => "page2.php", 
        "menu"  => array(
            array(
                "text" => "Nav Item 2.1", 
                "url" => "#", 
                "menu" => array(
                    array(
                        "text"  => "Nav Item 2.1.1",
                        "url"   => "http://www.google.com",
                        "target" => "_blank"
                    ),
                    array(
                        "text"  => "Nav Item 2.1.2",
                        "url"   => "page2-1-2.php",
                        "class" => "page2-1-2"
                    )
                ),
            ),
            array(
                "text" => "Nav Item 2.2", 
                "url" => "page2-2.php"
            )
        ),
        "class" => "nav-item-2"
    )
);

$nav = new Navigation($menu);

$nav->select('page2-1-2.php');

echo $nav->getMenu();
```

This will generate:

```
<div class="nav" id="primary-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/site/page1.php">Nav Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item-2">
      <a href="http://localhost/site/page2.php">Nav Item 2</a>
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/site/#">Nav Item 2.1</a>
            <div class="nav">
              <ul>
                <li target="_blank"><a href="http://www.google.com">Nav Item 2.1.1</a></li>
                <li class="page2-1-2"><a href="http://localhost/site/page2-1-2.php">Nav Item 2.1.2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://localhost/site/page2-2.php">Nav Item 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am aware of Pear [HTML_Menu](https://pear.php.net/package/HTML_Menu) but I wanted to create my own implementation. Initially, I was building the HTML using string concatenation, but I felt it had some limitations. So I switched to building the HTML using a tree structure which gives me more control on manipulating elements.

Anyways, any suggestions on how to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cosmetics**

You have a typo in the comment preceding the `buildMenuItem()` function: "Build menu" should be "Build menu item".

**Technical improvement**

In your `isNav()` function, since you don't need to get the corresponding key you'd better using `in_array()` instead of `array_search()`:

```
return in_array('nav', explode(' ', $node->getAttribute('class')));
```

It makes the code simpler, and causes less internal work.

On the other hand, you can get rid of double wrapping the menu (or its childs) by `<div><ul>...</ul></div>`: `<ul>` is enough, and can gather `id` of the primary level and `class` when defined.

**Strategy**

Here is the most important change I'd suggest, based on the idea that you can simplify your source `$menu` structure to gain readability (in the structure itself and in the code of the `Navigation` class), and maintainability about the different modifiers you could add further.

Currently the structure looks like this:

```
$meta_menu = [
  [
    'text' => <item text>
    'url' => <url>
    'hide' => TRUE
    'class' => <class>
    'target' => <target>
    'menu' => [
      [
        // ... child item(s)
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

I propose to change it to this:

```
$meta_menu = [
  <item text> => [
    <url> => [
      // ... child item(s)
    ],
    '#hide'   => TRUE|FALSE (default)
    '#target' => <target>
    '#class'  => <class>
  ],
];
// with <url> => NULL if there is no child
```

This way, the structure uses less nesting levels, taking advantage of the fact that the two main members `text` and `url` become keys (for the item, or for its childs). It is more compact, and easy to populate when defining a menu.
So your example of `$menu` becomes:

```
$menu = [
  'Nav Item 1' => [
    '#hide' => FALSE,
    'page1.php' => NULL,
  ],
  'Nav Item 2' => [
    '#class' => 'nav-item-2',
    'page2.php' => [
      'Nav Item 2.1' => [
        '#' => [
          'Nav Item 2.1.1' => [
            '#target' => '_blank',
            'http://www.google.com' => NULL,
          ],
          'Nav Item 2.1.2' => [
            '#class' => 'page2-1-2',
            'page2-1-2.php' => NULL,
          ],
        ],
      ],
      'Nav Item 2.2' => [
        'page2-2.php' => NULL,
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

And the `Navigation` class code:

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/site');

class Navigation
{
  private $doc;
  private $xpath;
  private $rootNode;

  /**
   * Initialize navigation.
   */
  public function __construct($menu) {
    $this->doc = new DOMDocument();
    $this->doc->appendChild($this->buildMenu($menu));
    $this->xpath = new DOMXpath($this->doc);
  }

  /**
   * Un-mark selected menu item.
   */
  public function deselect() {
    $liNodeList = $this->xpath->query("//li[contains(@class, 'selected')]");
    if ($liNodeList->length) {
        $liNode = $liNodeList->item(0);
        $classAttr = explode(' ', $liNode->getAttribute('class'));
        $key = array_search('selected', $classAttr);
        unset($classAttr[$key]);    
        $liNode->setAttribute('class', implode(' ', $classAttr));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Mark first occurrence of menu item containing link with URI as selected.
   * @param   $uri    string
   */
  public function select($uri) {
    $liNodeList = $this->xpath->query("//li[a[contains(@href, '" . $uri . "')]]");
    if ($liNodeList->length) {
        $liNode = $liNodeList->item(0);
        $classAttr = explode(' ', $liNode->getAttribute('class'));
        $classAttr[] = 'selected';
        $liNode->setAttribute('class', trim(implode(' ', $classAttr)));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Build menu.
   * @param   $menu   array
   * @param   $depth  int
   */
  private function buildMenu($menu, $depth = 0) {
    $ulNode = $this->doc->createElement('ul');
    $ulNode->setAttribute('class', 'nav');
    // set first nav as root
    if (!$depth) {
        $ulNode->setAttribute('id', 'primary-nav');
        $this->rootNode = $ulNode;
    }
    // add menu items
    foreach ($menu as $itemText => $item) {
      if (empty($item['#hide'])) {
        $ulNode->appendChild($this->buildMenuItem($itemText, $item, $depth));
      }   
    }
    return $ulNode;
  }

  /**
   * Build menu item.
   * @param   $menu   array
   * @param   $depth  int
   * @param   $index  int
   */
  private function buildMenuItem($itemText, $item, $depth) {
    // prepare item structure
    $liNode = $this->doc->createElement('li');
    $aNode = $this->doc->createElement('a');

    // iterate item properties
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
      switch ($key) {
        case '#hide':
          break;
        case '#class':
          $classAttr[] = $value;  
          break;
        case '#target':
          $liNode->setAttribute('target', $value);
          break;
        default:
          $url = $key;
          $childMenu = $value;
      }
    }

    // finalize item
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $url) !== false) {
      $classAttr[] = 'selected';
    }
    if (@$classAttr) {
      $liNode->setAttribute('class', implode(' ', $classAttr));
    }
    if (strpos($url, 'http') === false) {
        $url = BASE_URL . '/' . $url;
    }
    $aNode->setAttribute('href', $url);
    $aNode->nodeValue = $itemText;
    $liNode->appendChild($aNode);

    // add child items, if any     
    if ($childMenu) {
      $liNode->appendChild($this->buildMenu($childMenu, $depth + 1));
    }

    return $liNode;
  }

  /**
   * Get menu.
   */
  public function getMenu() {
    return $this->doc->saveHTML();
  }

  /**
   * Check if node element is nav element i.e. has 'nav' class name
   * @param   $node   DOMElement
   */
  private function isNav(DOMElement $node)
  {
    return in_array('nav', explode(' ', $node->getAttribute('class')));
  }
}
```

You may notice that I dropped the `createNav()` function, now using only `<ul>` it seems so simple to create it inside of `buildMenu()`.

What is also notabloy changed is the main part of `buildChildMenu()`, where a `foreach()` is needed to iterate properties of the new structure, which are then processed through a `switch()`.

Finally I used the (unloved, but IMO perfectly right here) error suppressor flag in `if (@$classAttr)`, so avoiding to have to initialize an empty `$classAttr = [];`.

_NOTE: I didn't even checked anything in the `deselect()` and `select()` functions.

Comment: Ah, how I love this site as I always get useful feedback. In particular, the new structure does make things easier and shorter. Thanks!

Comment: @Mikey Glad to help. I must say that we, answerers, also learn much: not only when reviewing but also from other answers like Paul's one here. All that makes things better for everybody!

Answer (score 2):

This is very good code.

### Re-usability

`BASE_URL` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` should be passed into the constructor as parameters.

I would suggest that this class should focus on building the `<ul>` and `<li>` part of the navigation and leave any container wrapping to the caller.  HTML5 provides the [nav](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) element.  This may be appropriate for the caller to use.  The method `createNav` is misleading it should either create a `<nav>` or it should be renamed to `createContainer`.

Sometimes just the top level or two of a menu is desired.  Having the depth to traverse the menu and build as a parameter could be good.

### Style

You have the current depth, but you don't add it to the output.  The CSS for styling might be easier if you add the current depth to the `<li>` items?

### Variables and Properties

One variable name was a little confusing.  `$depth` has a few different meanings. It could mean the current depth or be a limitation on how deep to traverse down the menu.

`$this->rootNode` can probably be removed?

The following could be made protected in case you want to extend this class?

```
private $doc;
private $xpath;
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your kind words. And you're so right about leaving the container wrapping out. It cuts down on a lot things. Thanks!